# Javascript TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code I want to remove an element from the `cart_products` array.

```
var cart_products = ["17^1", "19^1", "18^1"];
var product = 17;

$.each(cart_products,function(key, item) {
    if(item.indexOf(product+"^") !== -1){
        cart_products.splice(key, 1);
    }
});
```

But I get this error in Google Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's inside `cart_products` ?

Comment: what is the value of `cookie` ?

Comment: F.Y.I. you don't need to use jQuery to iterate through each element in an array. The Array prototype already has the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Comment: @MysterX `indexOf()` is also a string method. No suggestion that OP is looking to use an array inside the loop

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you're *modifying* the array while jQuery's `$.each` is looping over it, so by the time it gets to the end, the entry that used to be at index 2 is no longer there. *(I admit I'm a bit surprised `$.each` behaves that way, but I haven't used `$.each` in at least five years, so...)*

If the goal is to remove matches from the array, the better choice is [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var cart_products = ["17^1", "19^1", "18^1"];
var product = 17;

cart_products = cart_products.filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf(product+"^") === -1;
});
console.log(cart_products);
```

...or alternately if it's important to modify the array in-place rather than creating a new one use a boring `for` loop [as Andreas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895890/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-indexof-of-undefined/41896024?noredirect=1#comment70974402_41896024) looping *backward* through the array so it doesn't matter when you remove things:

```js
var cart_products = ["17^1", "19^1", "18^1"];
var product = 17;

var target = product + "^";
for (var index = cart_products.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
  if (cart_products[index].indexOf(target) !== -1) {
    cart_products.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
console.log(cart_products);
```

Comment: Um...wow, folks. I think the answer's been sufficiently upvoted. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas: :-) There is that. And it's better than my `findIndex`, which would only find and remove the *first*.

Comment: A perfect answer. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to use a jQuery each for this. Second, it's not a great idea to alter an array that you are operating on. If you're trying to remove elements from an array, use filter. Filter has the following signature:

```
someArray.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  // return a value that is truthy to keep an item or falsey to remove it
})
```

Filter returns a new array with only the values that match what you want. That means you don't mess with your original array, which is a good idea anyways. In your case it would look like this:

```
var filteredProducst = cart_products.filter(function(item) {
  return item.indexOf(product + "^")
})
```