# Javascript TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined Exchange Message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script on a page that I want to replace some system language.

```
<script> 
function xchangemessage2()
{ 
    xval = jQuery('[ID*="_UserMessageText"]').html(); 
    xvalpos = xval.indexOf("We could not find your information in our system. Please search again or contact us for assistance."); 
    xvallen = xval.length; 
    if (xvalpos > 0) 
    { 
         jQuery('[ID*="_UserMessageText"]').html(xval.substring(0, xvalpos+xvallen) + '  If you provided a valid user name, an email will be sent to the email address on file.') 
    } 
 } 
 Sys.Application.add_load(xchangemessage2); 
 </script>
```

I keep getting

> Javascript TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.

Comment: Verify that you have a `HTML` element with `id='_UserMessageText'` .

Comment: do `console.log(xval )` after line `xval = jQuery('[ID*="_UserMessageText"]').html();` and see what you are getting

Comment: If the selector doesn't match anything, `html()` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Already fixed, check below link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895890/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-indexof-of-undefined][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError)**: The *TypeError* object represents an error when a value is not of the expected type.

You are trying to access property `indexOf` of variable `xval` which is `undefined`.

**[String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**: The *indexOf()* method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

**[Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**: The *indexOf()* method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

**[undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)**: The global *undefined* property represents the primitive value `undefined`. It is one of JavaScript's primitive types.

Since `undefined` object is not a string or an array thus using `indexOf()` method gives an error. Value of `xval` is `undefined` as HTML element with id `_UserMessageText` is not found in DOM.

Would recommend to do go through [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) once before using it's features to avoid errors and using JavaScript at best.

Also checkout [jQuery features](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError and the script tags mean that your JS is running before your HTML code is loaded. To fix this, simply put the script tags at the very bottom of your body element, so the rest of the HTML loads before your JS.